# Laravel DB raw returns double sum

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

There are two tables: `users` and `score`. Score table has columns `game_id` and `points`.

This query

```
    return DB::table('users')
        ->where('users.id', 36)
        ->leftJoin('score AS education_score', function($query){
            $query->on('education_score.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->where('education_score.game_id', 2);
        })
        ->leftJoin('score AS experience_score', function($query){
            $query->on('experience_score.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->where('experience_score.game_id', 3);
        })
        ->groupBy(['users.id', 'users.name'])
        ->select([
            'users.name',
            DB::raw('SUM(education_score.points) AS education_score'),
            DB::raw('SUM(experience_score.points) AS experience_score'),
        ])
        ->get();
```

should return

```
[
    {
        name: "JANE DOE",
        education_score: 70,
        experience_score: 2
    }
]
```

instead it is returning exact double

```
[
    {
        name: "JANE DOE",
        education_score: 140,
        experience_score: 4
    }
]
```

Comment: You are having different `game_id` in `education_score` and `experience_score`?

Comment: yeah, education = 2 , experience = 3

Comment: Can you try using `innerJoin` instead of `leftJoin`? If possible can you share the data from the tables you are using here in the question?

Comment: Tried `innerJoin` with the same results. Sorry, can't share the table. But all relevant info is given.

Comment: Did adding `groupBy` solved the problem?

Comment: no. I tried it in `strict` mode, so `groupBy` became necessary. Added to avoid useless suggestions.

Comment: Can you try moving this line `->where('users.id', 36)` before `groupBy`? Also, you sure, that we don't have users with same id, name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting incorrect results because you are joining the same table twice.

Use a different approach:

```php
return DB::table('users')
    ->where('users.id', 36)
    ->leftJoin('score', 'score.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->groupBy(['users.id', 'users.name'])
    ->select([
        'users.id',
        DB::raw('SUM(IF(score.game_id = 2, score.points, 0)) AS education_score'),
        DB::raw('SUM(IF(score.game_id = 3, score.points, 0)) AS experience_score')
    ])
    ->get();
```

Comment: It also did a great job with group_concat if